# How to read a string starts with "PR" in a cell ( multiple strings in a cell) and write them to the next column

Tags: vba

```
Option Explicit

Const strText As String = "PR"

Sub InStrTakeNext10()
Dim MainString As String 'String1
Dim SubString As String  'String2
Dim TempString As String  'String3
Dim lastrow As Long, lCount As Long
Dim i As Integer,j As Integer

'---INPUT---
SubString = "SR"
'Also adjust the MainString line in the For Loop
'-----------

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("J3").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To lastrow
 MainString = Range("J" & i)
 If InStr(MainString, SubString) <> 0 Then
'HOW CAN I WRITE THE ALREADY FOUND STRING INTO THE NEXT COLUMN?????

    'MainString contains the SubString
    TempString = Mid(MainString, "SR" + 0, 10)


      For j = i + 1 To i + 10
        'Copy the next 10 lines to Column H
        lCount = lCount + 1
         Range("I" & lCount).Value = TempString

   '------ MID(C22,FIND("SR",C22)+0,10)
      Next j
      i = i + 10 'skip the next 10 cells
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[Please click here to see the Example -The PR numbers in the column c, and i need them to get added to the Column B after rows are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN3EI.png)

1.I Initially I have ID and Description Columns with data.
2. The Description section contains multiple strings starts with "PR". This PR is followed by 15 numbers ( maximum)
3. Need to read number of PR strings in the C cell and  add that number of raws below.
4. Then write that PR number on B columns for rows ( what is added)

Comment: `"SR"` is not a number and cannot be converted to a number, which what the second criterion of MID() is looking for.

Comment: Can you add some details to your question? Show us an example!

Comment: I have add an example

Comment: Please select on the "Example please see the PR numbers in the column c, and i need them to get added to the Column B after rows are added" takes you to the image